# How to search by text in a variable in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

The following code in my controller doesn't work:

```
@date = (Date.today - 1.day).strftime('%d.%m.%Y').to_s
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.moex.com/ru/derivatives/contractresults.aspx?code=Si-6.17"))
row = doc.xpath('//td[contains(text(), "#{@date}")]')
```

But if I change `"#{@date}"` to a real date like "25.05.2017", everything works fine:

```
row = doc.xpath('//td[contains(text(), "25.05.2017")]')
```

How do I search for text in a variable?

Comment: First of all, why do you use `"#{@date}"` when you can simply just use `@date`

Comment: I've tried both "#{@date}" and @date without any success

Comment: Consider preparsing outside the controller in a separate process and storing the information for later use. If the site is down or is slow it will affect your app's speed, making it look like your code is the problem. Also, if that action is called repeatedly, you'd end up DOSing the other site, potentially getting banned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully to your last expression:

```
row = doc.xpath('//td[contains(text(), "#{@date}")]')
                ^                                  ^
```

In Ruby [***only***](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html) the double-quoted string `"..."`  allows interpolation.

```
row = doc.xpath("//td[contains(text(), '#{@date}')]")
```

Comment: "only the double-quoted string "..." allows interpolation" Be careful how you say it: If `foo = 'bar'`, then the first three are true.
`"#{foo}" # => "bar"` `%(#{foo}) # => "bar"` `%Q(#{foo}) # => "bar"` `'#{foo}' # => "\#{foo}"` `%q(#{foo}) # => "\#{foo}"`

Comment: @theTinMan indeed, how about  `'%s' % foo # => "bar"` is it an example of interpolation?